# Plants Vs Zombies :- Switch House

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In Plants Vs Zombies there is an option to "Switch House" at Crazy Dave's shop. What exactly does this do. I've switched house and not noticed any difference in game play.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the XBox 360 version of the game, you can purchase additional blueprints from [Crazy Dave's Twiddydinkies](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Crazy_Dave's_Twiddydinkies) that change the appearance of your house on the [Leaderboard screen](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Leader_Boards). Using "switch house" is how you swap to one of your other houses.

Comment: That may explain why we're not seeing anything if it's XBox 360 only... Thanks.